# How to clear all data from shopping cart derryl decode in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cart

`Cart::clear()`  is not working correctly.

how can I erase all data from my cart?
it says
`Non-static method Darryldecode\Cart\Cart::clear() should not be called statically`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `\Cart::clear()`.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Heading section

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\DatabaseStorageModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition;
```

Function Section

```
public function clear()
{
    $userId = Auth::id();
    \Cart::session($userId)->clear(); // use user session 
    return redirect()->route('cart.index', ['message' => 'cart reset to empty']);
}
```